# Safari fails to pause animation when switching to a different tab

Tags: css, safari, frontend, css-animations

Context:

I am building a website with some animations, which I would like to pause when I switch between tabs. I tried 2 different animation approach: CSS and Javascript's request animation frame:

CSS Animation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            animation: moving 6000ms linear forwards;
           
        }

        @keyframes moving {
            from {
                transform: translateX(0px);
            }

            to {
                transform: translate(1000px);
            }
        }

       
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="box"></div>
    <button>Pause</button>
    <script>
        const box = document.querySelector(".box");
        const [anim] = box.getAnimations();
         window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", ()=>{
            if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden'){
                anim.pause()
            }
        })
```

Javascript Animation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            
           
        }

       

       
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="box" data-timeelapsed="0" data-duration="6000" data-traveldistance="1000"></div>
    <button>Pause</button>
    <script>
        const box = document.querySelector(".box");
        let animationID;
        const animationFunction = function(timestamp){
            let progress = (timestamp / Number(box.dataset.duration)) * Number(box.dataset.traveldistance);
            if (timestamp < Number(box.dataset.duration)){
                box.style.transform = `translateX(${progress}px)`
                animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animationFunction)
            }
            else {
                box.style.transform = `translateX(${box.dataset.traveldistance}px)`
            }  
            
        }

        animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animationFunction) 

        window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", ()=>{
            if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden'){
                cancelAnimationFrame(animationID)
              
            }
        })
       
       
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While I am able to pause the animation when switching to a different tab with the javascript animation, the same cannot be said for the CSS approach. Specifically, if you stay in the new tab for longer than the duration of the animation, the animation will cut to its final stage instead of picking up where it left off. I theorize that instead of pausing the animation the moment the the tab switching event occurs, safari only execute the event handler when focus is given back to the tab. This problem only exists on safari, either approach works fine on Chrome.

Comment: As a separate note, its better to offload all animations to css as it would result in event blocking and layout shifting if you heavily use js for animations.

Comment: @HariHarker Well, it seems JS is a better candidate for complex animation which you want a lot of control over. I have yet to find a proper way to pause CSS animation when switching tab that works universally across browsers